# Generating unique id for iphone

Tags: ios, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Hi I am developing small iphone application in which I want to generate unique id for my device. I am using following thing :

```
-(NSString*)uniqueIDForDevice
{
NSString* uniqueIdentifier = nil;
if( [UIDevice instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(identifierForVendor)] ) { // >=iOS 7
    uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
} else { //<=iOS6, Use UDID of Device
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    //uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);- for non- ARC
    uniqueIdentifier = ( NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid));// for ARC
    CFRelease(uuid);
}
return uniqueIdentifier;
}
```

So i tested this code locally. Mean Every time when I uninstall and install it again it will create same unique code for me. But when I push it to app store that time for every installation on same device it is generating different code. I want to generate same code for each installation on same device. Is there any method to do this. Need some help.

I want to generate a unique identifier for device which will be same for my device even I install and uninstall application many times. I am using OIS 7.0 version.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to identify ios device uniquely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179799/how-to-identify-ios-device-uniquely)

Comment: In simulator also, each time reset the contents and settings then check the id is unique or not

Comment: `identifierForVendor` is the recommended approach.  I have heard that a UUID in keychain can survive across re-installs, but I haven't confirmed it

Comment: I am using `identifierForVendor`. So then what I have to do? I have to store it in keychain. ?

Answer (score 1):

The identifierForVendor changes only after a system restore, you can check some of my test here:[iOS 7 access UUID value in an enterprise application (not for AppStore)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515222/ios-7-access-uuid-value-in-an-enterprise-application-not-for-appstore).
In case of iOS version lower than ios6 you can save the id in the keychain, it will persist even after app uninstall